# How to sort two vectors simultaneously in c++ without using boost or creating templates?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have two vectors with same sizes

```
vector<float> predictions;      //say {1.22, 3.22, 2.22, 4.22}
vector<int> indices;            //say {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

I sorted the values in predictions in descending order using

```
std::sort(predictions.rbegin(), predictions.rend());     //gives {4.22, 3.22, 2.22, 1.22}
```

Now I want to sort indices simultaneously with the predictions.

```
//to get {3, 1, 2, 0}
```

How do I do it without using boost and custom templates?

Comment: Why not boost? **Why not templates?**

Comment: Write your own sort function that takes both and whenever you swap an element in one do the same swap in the other.

Comment: I don't get why people keep wanting to not use convenient C++ features.

Comment: Create a class containing a prediction and an index, and sort a vector of those instead

Comment: @Hacketo It's weird though, templates are a core feature of C++. If your professor teaches you C++ and disallows templates he's doing it wrong.

Comment: @JameyD Speaking from what I have seen and what I went through in collage most beginning C++ classes start of as C using C++ syntax and they do not introduce "C++" until the end or the next level class.

Comment: @SuJit Not understanding them is not an excuses not to use them.  You should learn how templates work as they are a core principal of C++.

Comment: Your requirements are impossible. `std::vector` is a template and you cannot use a template without using a template.

Comment: As is `std::sort`; it's templated on the iterator type, which is itself templated on the `vector` type.

Comment: @NathanOliver and Vittorio Please see the Answer I added. If the things can be so simple, why should I use heavy boost or create my own templates?

Comment: I have edited the question header. I wanted the solution where I won't have to 'use' boost or 'create' my own template.

Comment: An alternative solution to the problem might be to only sort indices (using predictions as key, as rgcldr suggested) and leave predictions unsorted. Then you can look up predictions via the indices as needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine these two vectors into one with type like `std::vector<std::pair<int, float>>` and sort it instead. The compare function can be like this:

```
bool compareFunc(std::pair<int, float> &a, std::pair<int, float> &b)
{
    return a.second > b.second;
}
```

And sort the combined data like this:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compareFunc);
```

After this, you can get the sorted parts, i.e. its first component.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not getting. How do I use compare function?

Comment: I did this:    
std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> predictions;    
std::pair<int, float> p = {j, pixel[j]};
predictions.push_back(p);

Comment: Thanks for help! I did it without compareFunc;    
std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> predictions;    
sort(predictions.rbegin(), predictions.rend());

Comment: It's actually      vector<pair<float, int>> predictions;    sort function sorts vector<pair> by it's first component.

Answer (score 4):

This is slower, but it doesn't require pairing the data and doesn't require allocating a temp vector:

```
    std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
          [&predictions](size_t i, size_t j)
          {return predictions[i] > predictions[j];});
    std::sort(predictions.begin(), predictions.end(),
          std::greater<float>());
```

Answer (score 3):

@herohuyongtao 's answer is good, but uses templates.  You *should* learn templates.  If you don't want to do this though, just create your own struct

```
struct MyPair
{
    float prediction;
    int index;
};
```

and your own compare function

```
bool compare(MyPair &a, MyPair &b) { return a.prediction > b.prediction; }
```

Then bundle your vectors into a single `vector<MyPair>` and use `std::sort` on that and your `compare`.

Of course, `vector<MyPair>` is a template.  So was `vector<int>`.  You should learn templates!

Comment: Please see the Answer I have added. I did it without using compare function or struct.

Comment: But not without templates.

Comment: I am ok with using templates; I wasn't ok with creating templates.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally used, suggested by @herohuyongtao and it's working as expected.

```
std::vector<std::pair<float, int>> predictions;
float * pixel = output.ptr<float>( 0 );
for ( int j = 0; j < output.cols; ++j ) {
    predictions.push_back({pixel[j], j});
}
std::sort(predictions.rbegin(), predictions.rend());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the indices (assuming it is 0 to N sequentially) like:

`std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), compareFunc);`

using a compare function like:

```
bool compareFunc(int &a, int &b)
{
    return predictions[a] > predictions[b];
}
```

This will sort only indices but predictions can be accessed in sorted order using index values from indices!

Complete Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<double> predictions{ 1.22, 3.22, 2.22, 4.22 };
vector<int> indices{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };

bool compareFunc(int &a, int &b) {
    return predictions[a] > predictions[b];
}

int main()
{
    std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), compareFunc);
    for (auto i: indices) {
        cout << i << "\t" << predictions[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```